# getting null pointer exception exporting data from database to xml

Tags: java, sql, xml, dom, jdbc

Im trying this java code to export data from database using sql query, But getting a null pointer exception. getting no clue to remove it . Im getting this exception at the line in Bold font.

```
try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.newDocument();
    Element results = doc.createElement("Results");
    doc.appendChild(results);

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "hr", "hr");

    ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from departments");

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    while (rs.next()) {
        Element row = doc.createElement("Row");
        results.appendChild(row);
        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
            String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            Object value = rs.getObject(i);
            Element node = doc.createElement(columnName);
            row.appendChild(node);
            **node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value.toString()));**
        }
    }


    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(sw);
    transformer.transform(domSource, sr);

    System.out.println(sw.toString());


    con.close();
    rs.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Stack trace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.ProjectXML.ui.DataBaseToXML.main(DataBaseToXML.java:61)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: At which line are you getting error?

Comment: @CodeChimp here is the stack trace: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.ProjectXML.ui.DataBaseToXML.main(DataBaseToXML.java:60)

Comment: Im getting error at this line : 
node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value.toString()));

Comment: @user2190060 - Add the error to the post itself and kindly point out to us the line # 60 that causes the problem.

Comment: is `rs.getString(i)` is giving some value? have checked it using `System.out.print(value)` ?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to examine `node`, `doc`, and `value` objects before the problem statement is executed?

Comment: It would be value that is null, just add a check, and handle null (e.g. leave node empty).

Comment: @Vishal K 
    System.out.print(value)
gives the output as expected, but 
    rs.getString(i)
doesnot makes ny difference , still gives that exception.

Comment: @user2190060 - edit your post (see the "edit" link above) and paste in the stack trace there.

Comment: @PM 77-1 :-
yes u r right , doc gives null value, but I dont understand y its so. Please tell ,why it is giving a "null" value ?Where am I  wrong or how to overcome it ?

Comment: @user2190060 - According to you testing, at what point does `doc` become `NULL`?

Comment: @PM77-1 - Even when I add  `System.out.print(doc)` after  `doc.appendChild(results);` , doc gives nul value as output.

Comment: @user2190060 - What I mean: is it `NULL` from the very moment it's assigned its value?

Comment: yes it is giving `NULL` from the very moment it is assigned a value , i.e a child node ("results" here) is appended to it , as u can see in the code above

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add this simple piece of code inside the while loop:

```
if (value != null)
  node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value.toString()));
else
  node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(""));
  row.appendChild(node);
```

Full code:

```
public static String ConvertToXML1(ResultSet rs, String view)
  throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.newDocument();
    Element results = doc.createElement(view);
    doc.appendChild(results);

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    while (rs.next()) {
      Element row = doc.createElement("Row");
      results.appendChild(row);
      for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
        Element node = doc.createElement(columnName);
        // The added code is here
        if (value != null)
          node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value.toString()));
        else
          node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(""));
        row.appendChild(node);
      }
    }

    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();

    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(sw);

    transformer.transform(domSource, sr);

    return sw.toString();
  }
```